# How do I prepend http/https to a user entered string in flutter textfield?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using texteditingcontrollers and if a user enters `stackoverflow.com` I want it to be taken as `https://stackoverflow.com`, so I can open the link using `url_launcher` package. Can this be done in dart?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could be done using `Dart` language:

```
@override
Future<void> launchUrl({required String url}) async {
  url = checkUrl(url);

  try {
    final bool shouldContinue = await canLaunch(url);

    if (shouldContinue) {
      await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false);
      return;
    }

    throw Exception('Could not launch $url');
  } catch (e) {}
}

String checkUrl(String url) {
  if (url.startsWith('http')) return url;

  return 'https://$url';
}
```

You may also take a look at [string_validator](https://pub.dev/packages/string_validator). Instead of creating your `validating method`, you may use a package like this one.

If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.